# Regarding the setting of the url of the datasource db in the schema.prisma file

Tags: prisma

I want to set the URL in the schema.prisma setting by concatenating the strings as follows, but an error occurs.

My desire is to set it without adding the DATABASE_URL environment variable.

Is such a configuration possible?
I would be happy if I could simply use schema.prisma to concatenate the strings, but...

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = "postgresql://" + env("PG_USER") + ":" + env("PG_PASS") + "@" + env("PG_HOST") + ":" + env("PG_PORT") + "/" + env("PG_DATABASE") + "?schema=public"
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please remove screenshot. The code is  already in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`schema.prisma` file does not understand how to concatenate the environment variables as it is not a javascript or typescript file.
Prisma expects that you specify your environment variable in .env file

```
// .env file
DATABASE_URL_WITH_SCHEMA=${DATABASE_URL}?schema=foo
```

and in your schema.prisma file, you load it as shown

```
// schema.prisma
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

To learn more about using environment variables with Prisma, check out the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/development-environment/environment-variables)